# Django - get cookie without request

Tags: django, cookies, django-models

is it possible to get cookie value without request. I have list of editions of conquest on my page. If user selects one of editions I want to show only objects associated with current edition. I store edition id in COOKIES and I wanted to write custom model managers in which I filter objects by this id.

Or should it do differently?

Comment: You can't get *anything* without a request, because it's a web framework.

Comment: Without request, I mean without using request object directly for example in models.py. There is middleware solution: [link](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2853/) but I thought that exists simplier way.

Comment: That is horrible, and doing this is a very bad idea; apart from anything else, you're unnecessarily tying your models to your request. If you need something from the request, you should pass it there.

Comment: I know, I did not want to use it. So if I have 10 forms and in all this forms I have field ModelMultipleChoiceField which queryset I want to filter by value stored in cookie, I need pass request to all this form? It produces 10 times the same lines of code instead of one function in model manager (Objects.objects.with_current_edition()).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to understand some concepts.

Cookies: "Is a small piece of data sent from a website and stored in a user's web browser while the user is browsing that website"

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)

Most of the times you use cookies to store data that will control your user session, not your website. It means that you are trying to do, should be done directly into your code not using cookies.

Another reason is that you can change your cookie data, and probably you will have security problems. Thats why every django page has a csrftoken.

Anyway, in your case, I would mind to use something related with Ajax, then you can switch in tabs or whatever you have to control only the data you will be editing:

[Ajax concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))

[Using Ajax with Django](http://www.dajaxproject.com/)

Comment: "Most of the times you use cookies to store data that will control your user session, not your website." Exactly, my english is poor, so maybe you didn't understand me. I know it all. I'm using angular, but with ajax the flow should looks like this:
user clicks button > in views.py: Object.objects.filter(edition__id=editon) (edition form cookies) > return list of objects
But I want to filter in model manager, because for example in forms I want sth like: ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Object.objects.current_edition()) (current_edition - for user in his cookies)
I can ofc store it in db.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. So, the first time that you render your page/view, why you don't use the REQUEST object of django to get his cookie? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.COOKIES